# Como mover el centro del mapa en pixeles?

Tags: javascript, nextjs, react-leaflet

Tengo un mapa de react-leaflet,

```
const [center, setCenter] = useState({
  lat: null,
  lng: null,
});

 useEffect(() => {
    setCenter({
      lat: initLocation?.latitude || initLocation?.contentful?.fields?.geoCoordinates?.lat || initLocation?.lat || 0.0,
      lng: initLocation?.longitude || initLocation?.contentful?.fields?.geoCoordinates?.lon || initLocation?.lon || 0.0,
    });
  }, [initLocation]);

  <MapContainer
    center={[center.lat, center.lng]}
     ref={mapRef}
     scrollWheelZoom={false}
     style={{
       height: "100%",
       width: "100%",
     }}
     zoom={zoom}
   >

        <ChangeView
          center={[center.lat, center.lng]}
          zoom={zoom}
        />
```

Cada vez que ejecuto cambios en el mapa, el componente ChangeView se encarga de centrarlo. Este es mi componente ChangeView:

```
import { useMap } from "react-leaflet/hooks";

const ChangeView = ({
  center,
  zoom,
}) => {
  const map = useMap();
  map.setView(center, zoom);
  return null;
};

export default ChangeView;
```

> **PROBLEMA**:

*Lo que me sucede es que el popup personalizado tiene unos 400px de alto, y como el centrado del mapa es respecto del marcador, una parte del popup queda fuera de la vista del usuario. Yo quisiera que el centro del mapa se ubique unos pixeles mas abajo para asegurarme de ver todo el pop up*

**Hay alguna manera de posicionar el mapa en el eje vertical, unos 150px mas abajo?**